# How do I get user list from github in Android?

Tags: android, github

I need to get a list of all users of GitHub (avatar and nickname). The list should be with 'pull to refresh' update technique.

Is there any special library for this? Or could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the api documentation:

https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users

It gives the users list in order that they signed up.

**Update:**

To make it simple, use [this library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)(download latest jar and add it as external library). As it handles Async stuff automatically.

```
AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
params.put("since","0");
    client.get("https://api.github.com/users", params,
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                            Throwable arg3) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {

                        try {
                          String content = new String(arg2, "UTF-8");
                           //content is your required json response that can be parsed.
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                               e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                });
```

Comment: With a HttpGet, Pass a RequestParam as since=your_last_id

Comment: Remember to do it in AsyncTask

Comment: some example of usage would've been great!

Comment: thanks alot for that! But one more question. That **Header[]** parameter? What is the imported class stands for it? My IDE is messing with it. It proposes _com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.MessageFiller_ for it. Is it right?

Comment: org.apache.http.Header